# Why bootstrap sub-theme with sass starterkit is not working?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying [Bootstrap 7.x-3.6](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme.

But sub-theme for some reason is not working. I did follow the same procedure as described on the [Documentation page for Drupal 7](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/7).

I am describing here, what I did,

**1.** Installed fresh drupal 7.50 on localhost.
**2.** Down loaded [Bootsrtap 7.x-3.6](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and enabled but not make is default.
**3.** **Sub-theme:** I did copy **sass** folder from the starterkits. Paste in /theme folder and rename with `mysubtheme`. Rename the file-name `sass.starterkit` with `mysubtheme.info`. And inside that changed the `'name'`.

> [image]

**Final image of /theme folder**

> [image]

**4.** **Downloding Bootstrap:** Downloaded bootstrap file from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) as decribed in following image. I did select `Sass` option. Pasted to `/mysubtheme` folder, rename with `bootsrtap`.*(even to check, I did try all three options one by one, but same result)*

> [image]

**5.** Downloaded [Jquery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module also and enabled, default version was 1.50.

**Now,** Till this stage the site shows content but not a basic theme formatting. Comparative image below.

> [image]

What could be the reason or I am missing something.

Comment: Well I could go out on a limb and say you have to compile the SASS.

Comment: @JeffBurnz Hi, Well I have already compiled the SASS, as I am using other themes, i.e. Adaptive theme for other trial site which is in same `htdocs` of MAMP, that all working well with SASS. Do I have to do some special for this, recompile?

Comment: Have you set the bootstrap theme as your base theme in your .info file?

Comment: @MarkConroy Yes, it is reading like `base theme = bootstrap`.

Comment: You should add information about compiling SASS, and the name, number of lines in, and location of the resulting .css-file to your question. Your "Base theme" looks OK, but your "Subtheme with sass" screenshot looks like there is no css present, so *something* has gone wrong with the sub-theming - but it is impossible to pinpoint what it is without knowing more about the css generated for your sub-theme. Also, what subdirectories to you have in your subtheme (is there a css subdirectory)? Have you removed the CDN?

Comment: I did find the issue, in that `.info` file of subtheme in the last, there is a code `; Disable the CDN provider so compiled source files can be used.
settings[bootstrap_cdn] = ''`, I did comment out and now it is taking the same theme as base. BUT, still I am unable to use style.scss, I will update the infor regarding that.

Comment: @FreeRadical I have updated the image in question section. The issue of `not fetchign the base theme` is solved as i posted in above message. You also looks pointing put same thing by removing CDN, I did see your updated message after posting mine last one. Thanks, Still, the `style.scss` is not working, although it is separate isuue. I am reading `README.md`, will try that and will update.

Comment: @CodeNext I have the same problem. I'm wondering what to do next after downloading sass from getbootstrap.com and extracting it under mytheme folder. How to generate bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css. CodeNext did you solve this problem? If yes, please share us your solution. Thanks

Comment: @jaypabs 1. I was not able to get the original bootstrap styling to my sub-theme, but as I have mentioned in the answer how to get that. Now your issue seems different, it is like you wan to know, how to make the entire sub-theme using sass starter-kit and how to enable its all CSS, so you will be able to apply your CSS changes. I would say, if you visit the bootstrap theme page on [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) there you can find the [link](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap) and there you can follow the steps for sub-theming.

Comment: @jaypabs 2. Unfortunately, I still not able to figure out how to set-up theme with SASS, so eventually I moved to LESS..:( might be there could be a issue of composer or some issue to local environment...

Comment: @CodeNext Can you please tell me how did you compile sass under the subtheme that you created? I have already downloaded all necessary files to my subtheme folder and don't know what to do next. I'm using Windows, btw.

Comment: @CodeNext I get it to work but don't know if I am doing it right. I just compiled the style.scss and save it under css folder and seems the theme is working fine now. However, it seems that the file bootstrap.css is also compiled within style.css. Is this the correct?

Comment: @jaypabs I am not getting why the bootstrap.css comes in picture. You do not have to touch anything except SCSS folder, which has there files, `_default-variables.scss`, `overrides.scss`, `style.scss`, You just need to use `_default-variables.scss`, `overrides.scss`, and whatever your custom CSS you have to apply, you have to use `overrides.scss`, Amd do not need to use `styles.scss`. See description [here](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/starterkits%21sass%21README.md/group/subtheme_sass/7), how to use these files. You don't have to touch anything which is inside `bootstrap` folder

Comment: @jaypabs Did you find solution for your issues?

Comment: @CodeNext Yes. What I did is simply compile style.scss. And everything works as intended.

Comment: @jaypabs, Ok, and just read the link(here) in my last comment you will come to now which file you ahve to use and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@JeffBurnz](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8344/jeff-burnz) [@MarkCornoy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/13227/mark-conroy) and [@FreeRadical](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12076/free-radical) for their inputs.

The following setting needs to be disable in mysubtheme.info(*sass.starterkit* A original file). And may be [@FreeRadical](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12076/free-radical) want to point out same thing by asking `"Have you removed the CDN?"` in the his comment.

> ; Disable the CDN provider so compiled source files can be used.
>
> settings[bootstrap_cdn] = ''

After commenting out `settings[bootstrap_cdn] = ''` it does take the base theme setting.

Any more suggestion appreciated. For now, this solution works.